# Spark Dataframe - Add new Column from List[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a List[String] and add the value of these Strings as Column Names to an existing Dataframe.

Is there a way to do it instead of Iterating over the List. If Iterating over the List is the only way, how best can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be dump.. should have tried this before.. 
got answer after a little try:

```
val test: DataFrame = useCaseTagField_l.foldLeft(ds_segments)((df, tag) => df.withColumn(tag._2, lit(null)))
```